# Constraint symbol vs foreign key index name -> what's the difference?

Tags: mysql

In mysql foreign keys are defined like this:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Why do we need CONSTRAINT and symbol? It seems like there is index_name anyway - so I totally don't get the reason for CONSTRAINT keyword. Can someone clarify what it's for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CONSTRAINT` is the key word that tells MySQL that you wish to add a constraint. `[symbol]` is an optional name for the constraint. You can name it whatever you like. If you omit the name, MySQL will generate a name on its own, internally.

It's good to use the `fk` prefix like `fk_something`.

You'll need that symbol name when dropping the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_something;
```

You can get the symbol name using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;
```

You can't use an index name to refer to a constraint. Any index that may be added when you issue the `CONSTRAINT` clause may be automatically removed later (e.g. if an index is explicitly added that will serve in its place).

All of this is answered in more detail in the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL Ref document

> index_name represents a foreign key ID. If given, this is ignored if
>   an index for the foreign key is defined explicitly. Otherwise, if
>   MySQL creates an index for the foreign key, it uses index_name for the
>   index name.

Comment: well - right. But index_name is not a constraint symbol. What's contraint symbol is for?

Comment: @Dannyboy, with [symbol] you can define your own naming for the foreign key. omitting [symbol] part will create a FK with an auto-generated name.